# How do I concatenate PHP strings without making PHP copy values from one location to another in memory?

Tags: php, string, memory, concatenation, copying

I made a function which takes any number of words for a parameter and capitalizes the first letter of each word.

I looked at this site: http://www.carlconrad.net/en/2014/03/17/improving-php-performance/ and it states:

> Avoid string concatenations in loops. When placed in a loop, string concatenation results in the creation of large numbers of temporary objects and unnecessary use of the garbage collector. Both consume memory and can dramatically slow down script execution.

I'm trying to figure out how I can modify my code below to make it run faster. Is there another way to concatenate strings in PHP without relying on the value of the original?

I know in raw C language, I could use the address pointer of the string plus an offset within defined bounds to add data without worrying about the original string being copied elsewhere which sources claim what PHP does during concatenation.

Ideally, I want my string concatenation to work like the way this C code works (assume we are in the main() function here):

```
char string[1000];
memcpy(string,'ABCD',4); //place ABCD at start
memcpy(string+4,'EFGH',4); //add EFGH to the string (no previous string copying required)
```

Just plain concatenation without manipulating the previous value of the string.

This is my php code that needs advice on improvement:

```
function capitalize($words){
    $words=$words.' ';
    $returnedwords='';
    $eachword=explode(' ',$words);$numberofwords=count($eachword);
    if ($numberofwords >=1){
        $wordkey=array_keys($eachword);
        for($thiswordno=0;$thiswordno<$numberofwords;$thiswordno++){
            $word=$eachword[$wordkey[$thiswordno]];
            $returnedwords.=' '.strtoupper(substr($word,0,1)).strtolower(substr($word,1));
        }
        return substr($returnedwords,1);
    }
}
```

Any ideas how I can follow the websites recommendation to avoid string concatenation in loops like I have in mine?

Comment: why you dont use `ucwords` function of php?

Comment: I didn't even know such a function exists.

Comment: see my answer.. i placed a link for your reference so you can get some idea about all string function in php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In php it have function to make first word of string as capital.

example 1: ucword of string:

```
$str = 'this is test value of data';
echo ucwords('this is test value of data');
```

> output: This Is Test Value Of Data

example 2: create ucword string from array having many words:

```
$str = array(
    'this',
    'is',
    'test',
    'VALUE',
    'of',
    'Data'
);

$str = array_map('ucwords', array_map('strtolower', $str));

echo implode(' ', $str);
```

> output: This Is Test Value Of Data

for more detail have a look at: [PHP String Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php)